# Can't insert value into sql. Data_Type is binary

Tags: php, sql, laravel, binary

```
Query: $structure = DB::connection('sqlsrv')
    ->table('TB_USER')->insert([
    'sUserName' => 'testuser3',
    'nDepartmentIdn' => 15,
    'sTelNumber' => 59281292,
    'nStartDate' => 1482059457,
    'nEndDate' => 1945244457,
    'sEmail' => 'testuser3@yahoo.com',
    'bal' => 0,
    'lm' => 0,
    'dlm' => 0,
    'lmdt' => '12/18/2016',
    'bPassword2' => 1234
]);
```

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Implicit conversion from
>   data type varchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function
>   to run this query. [20018] (severity 16) [(null)] (SQL: insert into
>   [TB_USER] ([sUserName], [nDepartmentIdn], [sTelNumber], [nStartDate],
>   [nEndDate], [sEmail], [bal], [lm], [dlm], [lmdt], [bPassword2]) values
>   (testuser3, 15, 59281292, 1482059457, 1945244457, testuser3@yahoo.com,
>   0, 0, 0, 12/18/2016, 123456))

Answer (score 1):

One of the columns has `binary` type, but you're trying to insert string. Set this column to `varchar` or convert value to `binary` to fix this.

Comment: Error is because bPassword2 column type is binary not boolean.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's binary. Well, you got the idea.